# VBA Validation list default value

Tags: excel, vba, validation

Is there a way to have a default value appear from a validation list when it gets created in VBA? So far I have:

```
.Cells(j, 7).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & "Listname"
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Just explicitly set the cell's value after you add its validation rule :)

```
Dim defaultValue as String 'string right?
defaultValue = ... 'get the value you want from your [ListName]

.Cells(j, 7).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & "Listname"       
.Cells(j, 7).Value = defaultValue
```